# Disappearing Reputation

Tags: support

I visited SO yesterday ago and found that two reputation have vanished! The same thing happened today! The last time I lost rep was like three days ago when the asker unaccepted my answer bringing my rep from 433 to 418. Why is my reputation disappearing and where is it? Is there some rule of losing 2 rep per day or something?

Comment: Can you please provide a screenshot of your reputation tab with the "show deleted posts" checkbox ticked? I don't see any rep changes, so they are probably private and only visible to you.

Comment: That's a difference of 15 rep - might have been an unaccept.

Comment: I said that in my question already

Answer (score 3):

Rep does not disappear on its own. You can check [your reputation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4052384/pythonmaster?tab=reputation) to see the explanation for any changes.

It costs you 1 rep point to downvote someone's answer (although downvoting questions is free) and you lose 2 rep if someone else downvotes your post. Either of those things could be the cause of your lost 2 rep.

Comment: The deletion of a post to which you've suggested an edit may also reduce your reputation by 2.

Comment: @Boann, there is nothing new other than the unaccept. Is there another reason why this is happening?

Comment: @PythonMaster Curious. [A Google cached page](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:T0V3hq4YpKcJ:http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4052384/pythonmaster) on January 10th at 14:53 UTC confirms that you had 416 rep then. You now have 412, but your profile page shows you haven't voted in that time period, and if you had been downvoted it would be publicly visible in your reputation history, so it can't be that. I suspect it is what Shog9 said, that posts you suggested edits to have been deleted; but that this is rep loss not displayed properly in the reputation history.

Comment: Does the loss of rep due to deletion of a post shows up?

Comment: @PythonMaster Yes, it **should** be an entry labelled "removed" with a link to the post. Perhaps this is broken for suggested edit rep?

Comment: @PythonMaster you may need to go to the bottom of your rep tab and check the "show removed posts" box.